# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@502699b7

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm facing this problem from last 6 hours in my android studio..they say me to extract the resource file i also extract the files in my string.xml file

Comment: Check if you have any error with your resource files

Comment: Looks like a problem with encoding of languages, try removing Italian or French languages

Comment: Been stuck on the same issue for hours now. Were you able to resolve it?
I have tried changing all the resources used in the project (found some issues with reference to library assets-> now fixed) 

But the same issue is annoying me (the app works fine without library usage)
Once you add library import it gives you an error and I cannot track it down because the library is just an AAR file.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In case you want to see error: 
Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@20a882cd) to table.